# This bundle is invalid: which CFBundleVersion?

Tags: xcode, app-store

I'm trying to upload an app to the AppStore for testing with TestFlight.

At the end of the upload, I obtain a message stating:

> This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleVersion [2-15] in the Info.plist file must be a period-separated list of at most three non-negative integers. Please find more...

There is no `CFBundleVersion`in my Info.plist. I can see it only in the Target Properties. I checked every other Info.plist of the packages I import with SPM or Carthage and they use `<key>CFBundleVersion</key><string>1</string>`.

I tried to change the value in the Target Properties, using a simple digit, but this doesn't help.
I tried adding `CFBundleVersion` and other `CFBundle*` keys in the Info.plist, but that didn't help either.

What is stopping my upload?

[image]

[image]

My Info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <false/>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict>
        <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                <string>Default Configuration</string>
                <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
               <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is. Because you're viewing the plist file in `Property List` mode. You can change the view mode to `Source Code` to see the key `CFBundleVersion`

> In your project, right click on Info.plist file -> Open As -> Source Code

It's something like:

```
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
```

And you may need to double-check the current version in `Project -> Targets -> General`. Its location is in `Identity` section.

[image]

Comment: I see it in the Identity section, but no in the Info.plist (I update the question with the Info.plist)

Comment: Hm, it's weird, are you sure you're selecting the correct file? As the first attached image, it has to contain CFBundleDisplayName, UILaunchStoryboardName, etc. It can't be that short. Can you open `Build Settings`, and search for the path of `Info.plist file`?

Comment: Yes, it is. I searched with `grep`and I checked with `find . -name Info.plist`and there is only this Info.plist (others are in Carthage/). In the project.pbxproj I got even other keys that usually are in the Info.plist (such as INFOPLIST_KEY_NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription).

Comment: What did you see on Targets -> General -> Identity section -> Version?

Comment: Researching: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/xcode-13-missing-info.plist/

Comment: I got it, it's a new feature, the old style .plist is no longer necessary. XCode will automatically sync `Custom iOS Target Properties`. If you want to use the old style you may make it manually (with template [here](https://gist.github.com/leson1106/c1576e648975c6047a7d1e7dfa76e5b1)). Then replace with your own fields. You also need to change the list path and `Generate Info.plist File` key in Build Setting to false as the link above. However, I suppose correctly altering the version will be enough.

Comment: I tried your Info.plist, I tried an empty Info.plist (which generated more errors, of course), but nothing helps me.

Answer (score 0):

I finally discover that in a binary xcframework downloaded with Carthage CFBundleVersion was "2-15". I didn't notice before because `grep` showed me the content of the other imported Info.plist files, but only `Binary file .../Info.plist matches` for this xcframework and I skipped it.

Updated the binary xcframework, I was able to upload the app.